# Datasheet for this transistor?

Tags: transistors, datasheet

I found this transistor on a board that I have no idea where it came from and I want a datasheet of its current and voltage handling. Has anyone seen something like this? I have looked all,over the web for a datasheet and couldn’t fine one. If you can, that would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks for your time.

[image]

Comment: That's a Motorola part. [A forum thread from 2004](https://www.diyaudio.com/forums/parts/31178-carver-pm-1-5-power-transistor-sub.html) suggests that it's either a MJ15024 or MJ15025. Frustratingly, it doesn't say which one.

Comment: https://www.scrtransistor.com/transistor?search=540130-5 $6 but no data sheet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a manufacturer's internal part number. You'd have to find the service manual for the equipment it came from and see whether it provides a cross-reference to a generic part number.

Otherwise, the best you can do is reverse-engineer the circuit it came from and figure out what capabilities it had to have to work there. It's actual capabilities are (presumably) greater than that.

A transistor curve tracer would also give you some clues, along with knowing the power capacity of the TO-3 package that it's in.